# I am attempting to update a row in MySQL from PHP using update query where some paramerters need to be used twice

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am attempting to update a row in my database where the users IP address and email address from an email are the used in the where clause of the query.

```
public function insert_user_captured_data($userip, $didIclickemaillink, $emailclickedfrom, $fname, $lname, $emailentered, $submitclicked){
    $sql = "UPDATE testdata 
        SET useripclicked = ?,
        emailclickedfromhere = ?,
        userlinkclicked = ?,
        userfnameentered = ?,
        userlnameentered = ?,
        useremailentered = ?,
        usersubmittedform = ?,
        timestamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        WHERE useripclicked = ? AND emailclickedfromwhere = ?";
    $stmnt = $this->dbConnection->prepare($sql);
    $stmnt->bind_param("ssisssiss",$userip,$emailclickedfrom,$didIclickemaillink,$fname,$lname,$emailentered,$submitclicked,$userip,$emailclickedfrom);
    $insRes = $stmnt->execute();
    if (!$insRes) {
        throw new Exception("Error Processing Request: Row Not inserted $stmnt->error", 1);
    }
}
```

I am successful in the initial insert but want to update the second pass to fill in the rows after the user has filled out a contact form. I get the following error (in code tags to stand out)

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\wamp64\www\example.com\assets\php\database.php:73 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp64\www\example.com\assets\php\thankyou.php(37): Database->insert_user_captured_data('10.0.2.15', 'jfender@example.com', 'Jesse', 'Fender', 'jfender@example.com', 1) #1 {main} thrown in C:\wamp64\www\example.com\assets\php\database.php on line 73
```

Additionally removed some of the repeated values that really didn't need to be updated with the following as a result:

```
public function insert_user_captured_data($userip, $emailclickedfrom, $fname, $lname, $emailentered, $submitclicked){
    $sql = "UPDATE testdata 
        SET userfnameentered = ?,
        userlnameentered = ?,
        useremailentered = ?,
        usersubmittedform = ?,
        timestamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        WHERE useripclicked = ? AND emailclickedfromwhere = ?";
    $stmnt = $this->dbConnection->prepare($sql);
    $stmnt->bind_param("sssiss",$fname,$lname,$emailentered,$submitclicked,$userip,$emailclickedfrom);
    $insRes = $stmnt->execute();
    if (!$insRes) {
        throw new Exception("Error Processing Request: Row Not inserted $stmnt->error", 1);
    }
}
```

But am getting the same error, and printing out the error and stack trace have been no help at all...

What am I doing wrong? I'm currently using PHP 7.1.9, MySQL 5.7.19, and Apache 2.4.17 On a Windows 10 system I am using OOP mysqli, and have been inserting just fine in my table.

Answer (score 0):

Im so Sorry guys... I found the error... it happened in the prepare() and it was due to my entering an erroneous letter in one of the column names. here is the corrected code::

```
public function insert_user_captured_data($userip, $emailclickedfrom, $fname, $lname, $emailentered, $submitclicked){
    $sql = "UPDATE testdata 
        SET userfnameentered = ?,
        userlnameentered = ?,
        useremailentered = ?,
        usersubmittedform = ?,
        timestamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        WHERE useripclicked = ? AND emailclickedfromhere = ?";
    $stmnt = $this->dbConnection->prepare($sql);
    $stmnt->bind_param("sssiss",$fname,$lname,$emailentered,$submitclicked,$userip,$emailclickedfrom);
    $insRes = $stmnt->execute();
    if (!$insRes) {
        throw new Exception("Error Processing Request: Row Not inserted $stmnt->error", 1);
    }
}
```

Jesse Fender

Answer (score 0):

Nice, prepare returns false when there is an SQL error. To track them easier you can make a quick check. Hope it helps:

```
if ($stmt = $this->dbConnection->prepare("QUERY")) {
    $stmt->bind_param(...);
} else {
    echo "Prepare error: {$this->dbConnection->errno} - {$this->dbConnection->error}";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up putting `var_dump($stmnt);` and it output false and then the error rather the `$stmnt` so I figured it out... when i had doubled checked the sql statement i found that the `AND emailclickedfromhere = ?";`was actually `AND emailclickedfromwhere = ?";` which was what the error ended up being - Thank you though for your rapid reply :)